What s the solution to the third pattern?
The values of  the following  two items are solved and you have to solve the third one according to the logics
27=SDD   91=QBI   43 =?

This question appears to be from the Ratio Logica Test online, where the author states "No discussing test items with others or posting your solutions elsewhere." For this reason, I believe this question should be closed.
